# Generate a specific xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have to generate a xml file that looks exactly like this (only the values will be changed):

```
<emotionml version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml">
  <emotion xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml" category-set="http://www.w3.org/TR/emotion-voc/xml#fsre-categories" start="1508862134106" duration="30">
      <category name="anger" value="0.00"/>
      <category name="contempt" value="0.20"/>
      <category name="disgust" value="0.43"/>
      <category name="fear" value="0.00"/>
      <category name="joy" value="0.00"/>
      <category name="sadness" value="0.03"/>
      <category name="surprise" value="0.21"/>
  </emotion>
  <BEHAVIOR start="1508862134106" duration="30">
      <category name="Engaged" value="0.08"/>
  </BEHAVIOR>
</emotionml>
```

My tries always return something like this (this xml down is a test that Im doing to learn how to built the emotions one):

[my xml output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDKf2.png)

[image: my xml output]

Resuming: my xml ins not idented, the head starts with the xml tag (i want to start with the emotionml tag) and I don't know how to make the emotion tag with its attributes.

EDIT 1: (my code)

```
function index(){
    $pessoa = [
        'person' => [
            $_POST['username'] => 'nome',
            $_POST['email'] => 'email',
            $_POST['sexo'] => 'sexo',
        ]
    ];

    $xml = '<emotionml version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml"></emotionml>';

    array_walk_recursive($pessoa, array($xml, 'addChild'));
    print($xml->asXML());

    $xmlFile = fopen("teste.xml", "a");
    $escreve = fwrite($xmlFile, $xml->asXML());
    fclose($xmlFile);
}
```

Comment: Can you include your code, it's sometimes easier to fix existing code than write something completely different.

Comment: Ok, it is done.

Comment: How does desired output relate to current attempt? E.g., where is *email* in desired version? Do you start with a source XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleXML isn't very good at formatting output, you have to use DOMDocument and the various options to give you something a bit more as your expecting...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
$dom->save("teste.xml");
```

This replaces the file writing that you currently have.  It takes the output from `$xml->asXML()` and loads it into a DOMDocument and formats the output to the file.

To exclude the xml tag, you have to do some more processing, instead of the $dom->save at the end of the above code, you have to go back to writing the file out yourself, but this time using the output from the above code...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
file_put_contents("teste.xml", $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement));
```

Comment: Thanks, Nigel! You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem creating a simple text file and insert formated strings  on it:

```
$br = PHP_EOL;  $tb1 = "\t"; tb2= "\t\t";
$headerEmotion = '<emotionml version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml">'. $br;
$botEmotionml =  '</emotionml>'. $br;
$catEmotion =
            $tb2 . '<category name="anger" value="' . ($frame['emotions']['anger'])/100  . '"/>' . $br .
            $tb2 . '<category name="contempt" value="' . ($frame['emotions']['contempt'])/100 . '"/>' . $br .
            $tb2 . '<category name="disgust" value="' . ($frame['emotions']['disgust'])/100 . '"/>' . $br .
            $tb2 . '<category name="fear" value="' . ($frame['emotions']['fear'])/100 . '"/>' . $br .
            $tb2 . '<category name="joy" value="' . ($frame['emotions']['joy'])/100 . '"/>' . $br .
            $tb2 . '<category name="sadness" value="' . ($frame['emotions']['sadness'])/100 . '"/>' . $br .
            $tb2 . '<category name="surprise" value="' . ($frame['emotions']['surprise'])/100 . '"/>' . $br;

$xmlFile = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fwrite($xmlFile, $headerEmotion);
fwrite($xmlFile, $catEmotion);
fwrite($xmlFile, $botEmotion);
fclose($xmlFile);
```

Comment: You should never build XML by string values. Use DOM methods like PHP's [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: I tried, but I don't know why I was unable to create a specific xml file using these methods